Other methods of solving this question: finding $2y^4-8y^3-5y^2+26y-28$ for $y=1+\sqrt2+\sqrt3$

If $y=1+\sqrt2+\sqrt3$ then find the value of $$2y^4-8y^3-5y^2+26y-28$$

There can be many ways to do this question. I would like to know the shorter approaches for this question that are clever to think and interesting. I am posting my solution below and expecting some cool and out of the box answers.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Substitute √2+√3=π, find answer in form of π, resubstitute √2+√3  (jokes aside, can we get somewhere by bringing √2 to one side and squaring?)

@Gwen yea the main idea was to bring one term on the other side and square

$$
    y = 1 + \sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3} \Longrightarrow (y - 1)^2 = (\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3})^2 = 5 + 2 \sqrt{6}
$$
Bring $5$ to the LHS, and then square both side again,
$$
     (y - 1)^2 - 5 = 2\sqrt{6} \Longrightarrow [(y - 1)^2 - 5]^2 = 24
$$
Simplify the equation to get
$$
    y^4 - 4y^3 - 4y^2 + 16y - 8 = 0
$$
or,
$$
   2y^4 - 8y^3 - 8y^2 + 32y - 16 = 0
$$
Thus,
$$
   \begin{align*}
      2y^4 - 8y^3 -5y^2 + 26y - 28 &= (2y^4 - 8y^3 -5y^2 + 26y - 28) - (2y^4 - 8y^3 - 8y^2 + 32y - 16)\\
&= 3y^2 - 6y - 12 = 3(y^2 - 2y + 1) -15 = 3(y - 1)^2 - 15\\
&= 3(\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3})^2 - 15 = 3(5 + 2\sqrt{6}) - 15 = 6\sqrt{6}
   \end{align*}
$$

Splendid....it couldn't be any better

This is nice and simple (after reading it) ! (+1) for sure

We can rewrite the given expression as $2(y^2-2y)^2-13(y^2-2y)-28$
which is same as
$(y^2-2y)(2(y^2-2y)-13)-28$
which is equivalent to
$(y^2-2y)(2y^2-4y-13)-28$
which can be evaluated without much effort.

$$\begin{align*}
y-1-\sqrt 2=\sqrt 3 \\
\implies y^2+1+2-2y-2\sqrt 2y+2\sqrt 2=3\\
\implies y^2-2y=2\sqrt2(y-1)=2\sqrt 2(\sqrt 2+\sqrt 3) \\
\implies y^2-2y=4+2\sqrt 6\end{align*}$$
Input this value in your expression to get
$$(4+2\sqrt 6)(4\sqrt 6-5)-28=16\sqrt 6-20 +48-10\sqrt 6 -28=6\sqrt 6$$
Little late in answering :)

I would like here to stress the help that a software like SAGE can bring, using the concept of minimal polynomial. Here is the program :
 y=1+sqrt(2)+sqrt(3)
 m=minpoly(y)
 print(m)  #answer : x^4 - 4*x^3 - 4*x^2 + 16*x - 8

What does it means ? That
$$p(x):=x^4-4x^3- 4x^2 + 16x - 8$$
is a polynomial of smallest degree with integer coefficients having $y$ as one of its roots.
Writing
$$p(y)=y^4-4y^3- 4y^2 + 16y - 8\color{red}{=0}\tag{1}$$
under the form :
$$2y^4-8y^3=8y^2-32y+16\tag{2}$$
and replacing the LHS into the given expression yields (computation by hand):
$$3(y^2-2y-4)=6\sqrt{6}$$
Remark : of course, all the latter computations can be done by SAGE by adding, to the previous program, the following instructions
 p=2*x^4-8*x^3-5*x^2+26*x-28
 q=p-2*m
 show(q)
 z=q.subs(x=y).expand()
 show(z)

Important : SAGE is a public domain software. You can use it at once. Just call https://sagecell.sagemath.org/ , copy-paste your program into the "edit" window, then press "Evaluate" button. You will notice also that this is a multi-software platform : you can as well execute programs written in Python, Maxima, R, etc.

See here.

Any comment ?...
